# How to add shade to Image swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

I want to take the top image and add shade so it looks like the bottom.

[image][image]

I've tried;

```
.renderingMode(.template)
.accentColor(.black.opacity(0.5))
.foreGroundColor(.black.opacity(0.2)
```

and other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler by adding an `overlay`:

```
Image(...)
    .modifiers(...)
    .overlay(Color.black.opacity(0.1)
```

You can animate it too:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @State private var hover = false
    var body: some View {
        Image(...)
            .modifiers(...)
            .onHover { hover in withAnimation { self.hover = hover } }
            .overlay(Color.black.opacity(hover ? 0.2 : 0))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer a negative brightness:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("green-phone-pocket 2")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .brightness(-0.3)
    }
}
```

| No brightness modifier | -0.1 | -0.3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Normal image] | [image: Image slightly darker] | [image: Image even more darker] |

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, though I would prefer a predefined way.

```
ZStack {
   Image("green-phone-pocket 2")
   Color.black.opacity(0.5)
}
```